# My computer keeps crashing BSOD Memory management but rams sticks are good

Tags: windows, memory, bios, bsod, crash

Around a year ago I built my first PC, multiple parts have been added throughout this elapsed time (AIO, different fans, and peripherals). Nonetheless, lately I have been having issues with BSOD more frequently than before. Even after performing a clean install of Windows 11 today, I had another BSOD, although the reason this time was `SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION`.

The main ones are usually `MEMORY_MANAGEMENT`. I have performed all kinds of tests on the computer, both for software and Hardware (changing the sticks positions, cleaning up the contacts carefully, memtest86, regular memory test from Windows) and none of it has shown any kind of problem with the RAM whatsoever. It's becoming frustrating to the point it's sometimes unbearable to use the PC for big projects because I can never know if a BSOD will make me lose all my progress.

The specs for my computer are the following : (Apologies for being in another language)

```
Nom du système d’exploitation   Microsoft Windows 11 Famille
Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621
Autre description du système d’exploitation Non disponible
Fabricant du système d’exploitation Microsoft Corporation
Fabricant   ASUS
Modèle  System Product Name
Type    PC à base de x64
Référence (SKU) du système  SKU
Processeur  AMD Ryzen 7 5800X 8-Core Processor, 3801 MHz, 8 cœur(s), 16 processeur(s) logique(s)
Version du BIOS/Date    American Megatrends Inc. 2803, 27/04/2022
Version SMBIOS  3.3
Version du contrôleur embarqué  255.255
Mode BIOS   UEFI
Fabricant de la carte de base   ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
Produit de la carte de base ROG STRIX B550-F GAMING
Version de la carte de base Rev X.0x
Rôle de la plateforme   Bureau
État du démarrage sécurisé  Activé
Configuration de PCR 7  Élévation requise à afficher
Répertoire Windows  C:\Windows
Répertoire système  C:\Windows\system32
Périphérique de démarrage   \Device\HarddiskVolume6
Option régionale    France
Mémoire physique (RAM) installée    32,0 Go
Mémoire physique totale 31,9 Go
Mémoire physique disponible 22,6 Go
Mémoire virtuelle totale    36,9 Go
Mémoire virtuelle disponible    24,6 Go
Espace pour le fichier d’échange    5,00 Go
```

The RAM sticks are a pair of Corsair Vengeance LPX DDR4 (2 sticks of 16GB each which are currently running at 2133 Mhz default, I haven't really tweaked anything from the BIOS).

I also got a hand of the dumpfile this time although I can't really interpret properly the information displayed. I really wish to know if the issue is hardware-related so I can just change the RAM sticks and deal with the situation, but as usual with electronics is not as simple as that. I do have to consider the fact that living in South Florida I have been victim of sudden power outages, although ever since I have my own UPS and have not seen any visible problem on the computer, nor any other electronic that has suffered those cuts of electricity.

This is the information displayed on the last dumpfile :

```
KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 30

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 42

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Other.Mb
    Value: 25

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Read.Mb
    Value: 1

    Key  : Analysis.IO.Write.Mb
    Value: 61

    Key  : Analysis.Init.CPU.mSec
    Value: 187

    Key  : Analysis.Init.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 2401132

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 130

    Key  : Bugcheck.Code.LegacyAPI
    Value: 0x1a

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.AsUlong
    Value: 1008

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.DiagDataWrittenToHeader
    Value: 1

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.ErrorCode
    Value: 0

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.KernelGeneratedTriageDump
    Value: 1

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.LastLine
    Value: Dump completed successfully.

    Key  : Dump.Attributes.ProgressPercentage
    Value: 0

    Key  : Failure.Bucket
    Value: MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT

    Key  : Failure.Hash
    Value: {e3faf315-c3d0-81db-819a-6c43d23c63a7}

    Key  : MemoryManagement.PFN
    Value: 400000


BUGCHECK_CODE:  1a

BUGCHECK_P1: 41792

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffa180f578ecf8

BUGCHECK_P3: 400000000

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

FILE_IN_CAB:  092623-9812-01.dmp

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  
You can run '.symfix; .reload' to try to fix the symbol path and load symbols.

WRONG_SYMBOLS_TIMESTAMP: aacd0d1d

WRONG_SYMBOLS_SIZE: 1047000

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff80435000000 nt

DUMP_FILE_ATTRIBUTES: 0x1008
  Kernel Generated Triage Dump

MEMORY_CORRUPTOR:  ONE_BIT

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffda8e`7199ed98 fffff804`354cd836     : 00000000`0000001a 00000000`00041792 ffffa180`f578ecf8 00000004`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffda8e`7199eda0 fffff804`35333be6     : ffffda8e`7199f270 ffffa180`f578eff8 ffffe966`a8f50027 ffffa689`ad4e7740 : nt!MmIsNonPagedSystemAddressValid+0x6d1c6
ffffda8e`7199ee90 fffff804`35333faa     : ffffda8e`00000000 ffffa689`ad4e7740 ffffa1d0`00000000 ffffda8e`7199f2c0 : nt!ExAcquireSpinLockSharedAtDpcLevel+0x16c6
ffffda8e`7199ef20 fffff804`35333faa     : ffffda8e`7199f270 ffffa689`ad4e7740 ffffa1d0`00000000 ffffda8e`7199f2d0 : nt!ExAcquireSpinLockSharedAtDpcLevel+0x1a8a
ffffda8e`7199efb0 fffff804`35333faa     : ffffda8e`7199f270 ffffa689`ad4e7740 ffffa1d0`00000000 ffffda8e`7199f2e0 : nt!ExAcquireSpinLockSharedAtDpcLevel+0x1a8a
ffffda8e`7199f040 fffff804`35333881     : 00000000`00000000 ffffa689`ad4e7740 00000000`00000000 ffffda8e`7199f2f0 : nt!ExAcquireSpinLockSharedAtDpcLevel+0x1a8a
ffffda8e`7199f0d0 fffff804`35351b82     : ffffda8e`7199f270 ffffda8e`00000001 00000000`00000002 ffffda8e`00000000 : nt!ExAcquireSpinLockSharedAtDpcLevel+0x1361
ffffda8e`7199f1d0 fffff804`35217f1e     : ffffa689`ad4e7590 ffffa689`ac84d080 ffffda8e`7199f570 ffffa689`ac84d780 : nt!Ordinal7+0x8fc2
ffffda8e`7199f4e0 fffff804`356816a7     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 ffffa689`ad4e70c0 : nt!ExReleaseSpinLockExclusiveFromDpcLevel+0x39e
ffffda8e`7199f530 fffff804`3569f6bd     : 000001ea`f16c0000 ffffa689`b1b6db00 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!NtCreateSection+0x1327
ffffda8e`7199f5f0 fffff804`3569f283     : ffffa689`b1b6db00 00000000`00000000 ffffa689`ac84d080 00000000`00000000 : nt!PsWow64GetProcessMachine+0xffd
ffffda8e`7199f620 fffff804`357ded9d     : ffffa689`b1b6dec0 ffffa689`b1b6dec0 ffffa689`b1b6dec0 ffffa689`ad4e70c0 : nt!PsWow64GetProcessMachine+0xbc3
ffffda8e`7199f650 fffff804`356c99c9     : ffffffff`00000000 ffffffff`ffffffff 00000000`00000001 ffffa689`ad4e70c0 : nt!NtMapViewOfSection+0x12fd
ffffda8e`7199f6d0 fffff804`357aebc2     : ffffa689`ad4e70c0 ffffdf85`a4b7d8f0 ffffda8e`7199f8f9 00000000`00000000 : nt!FsRtlNotifyFilterReportChangeLiteEx+0xc29
ffffda8e`7199f760 fffff804`357acd68     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 ffffa689`ac84d0f4 00000064`e674d000 : nt!KeUserModeCallback+0xe02
ffffda8e`7199f860 fffff804`3522f67d     : fffff804`3500ece8 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : nt!MmPageEntireDriver+0xc68
ffffda8e`7199f8a0 fffff804`35418810     : 00000000`00000001 ffffda8e`7199f960 00000000`00000000 ffffa689`ad4e70c0 : nt!KeSetCoalescableTimer+0x180d
ffffda8e`7199f960 fffff804`3542748f     : ffffa689`ac84d080 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x4a50
ffffda8e`7199faa0 00007ffb`0a66f2e4     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!setjmpex+0x8d0f
00000064`ec7ff5c8 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ffb`0a66f2e4


MODULE_NAME: hardware

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BIT

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {e3faf315-c3d0-81db-819a-6c43d23c63a7}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

I really would appreciate any help with this situation because I would like to fix my pc, and getting a new one doesn't really seem like an appropriate solution after having invested so much time and money on this one. Thank you in advance for anyone who may found interest in my question and wish to help me figure this out.

PS : I ran sfc /scannow and it found some errors but I have done this before and it hasn't really fixed the problem in itself.

Comment: Try to reduce system clock if the BIOS permit that.